# Delete the data in cassandra for specific time period

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax, cassandra-cli, cqlsh

Let say I want to delete the data which is dumped into my cassandra cluster for a specific time period (9PM to Midnight). How to do that?

I know we need to create a column with timestamp and retrieve it but my schema does not contain timestamp column now. How to delete it with out extra column.

Answer (score 1):

Use TTL:

http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/dml/using_cql#use-cql-ttl

```
INSERT INTO NerdMovies (movie, director, main_actor, year)
                VALUES ('Serenity', 'Joss Whedon', 'Nathan Fillion', 2005)
USING TTL 86400;
```

You need to calculate the number of seconds to the timestamp you want to delete the column and set TTL, and it will get deleted when that many seconds pass.

Comment: I want to delete the data which is already exists in cassandra. We accidentally added some information to the wrong cluster for specific time period and now we need to delete that.

Comment: My bad, you can use writetime function

"select record_id, writetime(title) from records;"

you can query for specific timestamp, get their primary key, and in a loop delete those columns

Comment: How to query for a specific time stamp. I think we cannot use writetime in where clause. Is there a way say time > 9PM and time < 12AM?

Comment: You can't do this operation in one step, and you especially cannot do this in bulk (one delete statement to remove everything).  You'll have to read all rows, figure out if writetime falls into the problematic window, and then issue individual delete queries.

Comment: That is very pain full process.That answer's my question. Thank you guys.